# Function converges uniformly but not analytic on the boundary

Tags: complex-analysis

If the Laurent series for $f(z)$ converges on the boundary of an annulus , is $f(z) $analytic on the boundary ?

The answer is No

Consider the following series $$f(z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n^2}$$

It's obvious that $f(z)$ is uniformly convergent on $\frac{1}{2} \leq |z| \geq 1$

Now I want to prove that $f $ is not analytic for $|z|=1$

$$|z|=1 \Rightarrow f'= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}$$

So $f$ is not analytic since the series diverge

Is my solution is correct ?

Thank you

Comment: If $f(z)$ is analytic then $f'(z)$ is analytic and in particular it is bounded and continuous. You need to say that $\lim_{r \to 1^-} f'(r) =\lim_{r \to 1^-}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{r^n}{n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} = \infty$ so $f$ isn't analytic at $z=1$

Comment: note: Functions don't converge or diverge, series do.

Comment: What does "analytic on the boundary mean"?

Comment: (If possible) we extend the function by analytic continuation where it isn't defined, and analytic at a point $a$ means analytic on some open disk $|z-a| < \epsilon$. Note that your function is analytic on $|z|\le 1, z \ne 1$